# How do I work out the complexity of the following code snippets?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am sort of a beginner with big O notation and algorithmic complexity. I am trying to work out the complexity of the following two java methods which both do the same thing. However one will be slightly faster.

```
ArrayList<Person> filter1(Person x, ArrayList<Person> people){
  ArrayList<Person> friends = new ArrayList<Person();
  for (Person y: people) friends.add(y);
  for (Person y: people) if (!x.knows(y)) friends.remove(y);
  return friends;
}

ArrayList<Person> filter2(Person x, ArrayList<Person> people){
  ArrayList<Person> friends = new ArrayList<Person();
  for (Person y: people) if (x.knows(y)) friends.add(y);
  return friends;
}
```

(knows() is a boolean method that returns true if x is a friend of y, false otherwise)

I initially thought that both filter1 and filter2 would run at O(n) time, but looking back on it would it be correct to say that filter1 would take O(n + n) time (can this be simplified to O(n)?) and that filter2 would take O(n) time because it only iterates through people once?

Or have I completely missed the point?

Comment: The first one is actually in `O(n^2)` since `add` inserts `y` [at the end of the list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-), so `remove` will iterate through the whole list. If you want to make it `O(n)`, go `friends.remove(friends.size()-1)` instead.

Comment: First thing first O(n+n) is O(n). Now, keeping things simple...in filter1 you are first adding and then removing (adding and removing takes time) but in filter2 you are directly adding based on some condition so don't you think this will run faster?

Answer (score 2):

> would it be correct to say that filter1 would take O(n + n) time (can this be simplified to O(n)?) and that filter2 would take O(n)

*O(n + n)* can be indeed be simplified to *O(n)*. But `filter()` is not *O(n)*.

First, a quote about time complexity from the `ArrayList` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) (emphasis mine):

> The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run in constant time. **The add operation runs in amortized constant time**, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. **All of the other operations run in linear time** (roughly speaking).

Let's analyze the code for `filter1()`:

```
List<Person> filter1(Person x, List<Person> people){
    List<Person> friends = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Person y: people) {        // O(n)
        friends.add(y);             // amortized constant time
    }
    for (Person y: people) {        // O(n)
        if (!x.knows(y)) {
            friends.remove(y);      // O(n)
        }
    }
    return friends;
}
```

So, since `List.remove()` is *O(n)*, **`filter1()` is *O(n + n<sup>2</sup>) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)***.

Now the `filter2()` code:

```
List<Person> filter2(Person x, List<Person> people){
    List<Person> friends = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Person y: people) {        // O(n)
        if (x.knows(y)) {
            friends.add(y);         // amortized constant time
        }
    }
   return friends;
}
```

So **`filter2()` is *O(n)***.

Now, to clear the confusion about two functions with same complexity but different running times, consider the following functions:

- *h<sub>1</sub>(n) = n = O(n)*
- *h<sub>2</sub>(n) = 1000 · n = O(n)*

The fact that *h<sub>1</sub>(n)* and *h<sub>2</sub>(n)* are both *O(n)* doesn't mean that they must run as fast as each other. In fact *h<sub>2</sub>(n)* running time is a thousand times greater than *h<sub>1</sub>(n)*. Having *O(n)* time complexity just means both functions increase linearly as the value of *n* increases.

Consider the *big O* definition:

> *f(n) = O(g(n))* means *c · g(n)* is an upper bound on *f(n)*. Thus there exists some constant *c* such that *f(n)* is always *≤ c · g(n)*, for a large enough *n*.

To apply the definition to *h<sub>1</sub>(n)*, considering *f(n) = n* and *g(n) = n*, we need to find a constant *c* such that for all sufficiently large *n*, *f(n) ≤ c · g(n)*. In this case, *n ≤ c · n* for any *c ≥ 1*, so we prove that *h<sub>1</sub>(n) = O(n)*.

Now for *h<sub>2</sub>(n)*, considering *f(n) = 1000 · n* and *g(n) = n*, we need to find a constant *c* such that for all sufficiently large *n*, *f(n) ≤ c · g(n)*. In this case, *1000 · n ≤ c · n* for any *c ≥ 1000*, so we prove that *h<sub>2</sub>(n) = O(n)*.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in saying that `O(n+n) = O(2n)` can be simplified to `O(n)`.

For `filter1()`:
Each of the for loop takes `O(n)`, so `O(n) + O(n) = O(n)`, but according this [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) the `friends.remove` will also take `O(n)` as it has to iterate through the whole list to find the item and remove it. However, `friends.add` takes O(1) to add the item [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-).

So, the complexity calculation goes something like this

```
(O(n) * O(1)) + (O(n) * O(n))
  = O(n) + O(n^2)
  = O(n^2)
```

For `filter2()` it is `(O(n) * O(1)) = O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

Big-O only cares about the general shape of the curve, not the coefficients applied to it.

So if you calculate a complexity `O(n + n)`, you should simplify it to `O(2n)` and then remove the coefficient for `O(n)`.

Both of your examples run in linear time with respect to the number of people.  From a Big-O perspective, the two filters are equivalent.

Comment: your assumption that both algorithms are in `O(n)` is based on the false assumption that all operations inside the loop are within `O(1)`. See the other answers about ArrayList.remove()

Comment: Good call, I missed that.